# Can I Add SpringBoot Framework to Existing Maven Project

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I have a Maven Project in Eclipse and now I need to add database connectivity. My textbook did all json tutorials in Maven. Now in this chapter on JDBC they are using SpringBoot.

Can I convert the project to SpringBoot? Or start a SpringBoot and import my previous Maven classes.

Comment: Look at this http://start.spring.io/ you can add the proper dependencies from a spring boot pom.xml and the parent and stuff necessary.

Comment: This is an old post, so this is just for future reference.  Spring Boot is certainly a valid (and to many, preferable) way to add database connectivity.  However, it is not by any means the only way. You do not have to use Spring Boot in a project to talk to JDBC.  It can be done by including necessary dependencies.

Answer (score 13):

[Here is described](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-maven-installation) how to use maven for a SpringBoot Project.

You will need to modify your existing `pom.xml` to add something like this to make it a SpringBoot Project:

```
<!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<!-- Add typical dependencies for a web application -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<!-- Package as an executable jar -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 7):

**Convert Maven Project to SpringBoot**

- **Ist option :Spring Boot Using parent POM**

Add following dependencies in pom.xml file**:-

1.) **Inheriting the starter parent(spring-boot-starter-parent)**: spring-boot-starter-parent is a special starter that provides useful Maven defaults.

2.) **spring-boot-starter-web** :- Starter for building web, including RESTful, applications using Spring MVC. Uses Tomcat as the default embedded container.

3.) **spring-boot-maven-plugin**:- Spring Boot includes a Maven plugin that can package the project as an executable jar.

here is pom.xml :-

> ```
> <!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
> <parent>
>     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
>     <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
> </parent>
>
> <!-- Add typical dependencies for a web application -->
> <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
> </dependencies>
>
> <!-- Package as an executable jar -->
> <build>
>     <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>         </plugin>
>     </plugins>
> </build>
> ```

- **2nd option:Using Spring Boot without the Parent POM**

Not everyone likes inheriting from the spring-boot-starter-parent POM. You may have your own corporate standard parent that you need to use or you may prefer to explicitly declare all your Maven configuration.

If you do not want to use the **spring-boot-starter-parent**, you can still keep the benefit of the dependency management (but not the plugin management) by using a **scope=import dependency**, as follows:

> < dependency> < !-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
>   < groupId>org.springframework.boot< /groupId>
>   < artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies< /artifactId>
>   < version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT< /version>     < type>pom< /type>
>   < scope>import< /scope>   < /dependency>

Fore more details find here in Spring Boot Docs:-  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-maven-installation

Comment: This is the exact link provided by [Simulant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29363882/3789665), accepted or not. This does not seem to answer the question. (Regardless of whether the content linked might: see [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer))

Answer (score 6):

1) Add Spring boot starter Parent and Web in **Pom.xml** file

2) Add @SpringBootApplication in the **main** class

3) Add SpringApplication.run(App.class, args); in main method.

Comment: What if there is no main class? What if its  a sub-module like  library module?

Comment: you dont have to have main class. spring boot library is also possible. you dont have to use SpringBootApplciaiton

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Springboot with Maven as dependency management.
You will have to add spring boot dependencies

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Also add @SpringBootApplication and @EnableAutoConfiguration in the main class

Answer (score 0):

I will face this question in two more interviews so it can help full your self also.
[image: Converting the standard alone application to spring boot]

Simply right-click on your project select "Configure" and choose on "convert to Maven Project" then it will create or application as maven and [image: explicitly add maven dependencies which we want to required].