# Run a Java Application with Embedded Jetty Server on Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, embedded-jetty

I am new to docker and I have a java application that runs on embedded jetty server that I want to run in a docker container.
As I understood from my readings, I need to create a dockerfile to create the image then run it on a container. But now I am a little confused while constructing the dockerfile. What is the base image I should use; should it be jetty image or java8 image?

Comment: How do you run the application when you are running it outside of Docker? From your description if jetty is already embedded in your application, you just need a java8 image

Comment: I run it from eclipse as normal java application (run as -> java application)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need a Jetty docker base image. You can use a jdk or jre base image like https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk

Comment: This is the correct answer @RandaElBehery - if you can run with standard java outside of docker, then this is all you need to run the same embedded-jetty application from within docker.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not sure which image to start with take a look at the Dockerfiles for those images to identify what is or is not in the image.

In your case, you can take a look at one of the jetty images here

https://github.com/appropriate/docker-jetty/blob/997e9496cc30fbc9afee70d7924e6f6a4a93e116/9.4-jre8/Dockerfile

I chose to link the Dockerfile that is based on `openjdk:8-jre` since it fits your requirements in particular.

Comment: Those images are for running a webapp within a Standalone version of Jetty using the `${jetty.home}` and `${jetty.base}` deployment concepts.  Not appropriate for running an embedded-jetty application that @RandaElBehery already has functioning with standard Java.

Answer (score -1):

1. If possible convert your [application into a spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360631/can-i-convert-maven-project-to-springboot) app. Not sure what you mean by java application. elaborate. web app? lib? api?
2. Dockerfile base image pull is up to you, if you can pack JAVA, then you can ideally run your container anywhere, need not worry about platform runtime.
3. If you convert your application into a spring boot app, the jetty integration and start up is taken care by spring boot. no configs, FROM on Dockerfile required from you.
4. On a Brief note, convert your application into a spring boot app, FROM JAVA:, COPY yourjar, RUN yourjar. Done.

Comment: By java application, I mean java application java based api, sorry for the confusion
If I can't convert the application to spring boot currently, what should I do ?

Comment: If you can’t convert then you need to pull Two dependencies.  Java and jetty or tomcat.  Both gets packed in your image.  Then you copy your jar to jetty and then run jetty start.  All these will go into your Dockerfile.  If you need sample in an get you one.  Although easily findable in stackoverflow.

Comment: Spring Boot is not necessary to accomplish the end goals laid out by @RandaElBehery

Comment: Never mentioned it’s necessary.  It’s favourable. It’s upto @RandaElBehery to choose which one.

Comment: @SriniM, sometime you have a microservice, all you need is DI and you just add Guice instead of Spring Boot. You don't have to migrate to Spring Boot, it's optional